# Await vs await Task.Delay trying to learn

Tags: c#, async-await

If I have code that says:

```
public async Task Test1()
{
    Task task1 = MakeEggAsync();
    Task task2 = MakeBaconAsync();

    await Task.WhenAll(task1, task2);

}

async Task MakeBaconAsync()
{
    while (CookIsBusy)
    {
        //      
        await Task.Delay(100);
    }
}

async Task MakeEggAsync()
{
    await makeEgg2Async();
}

async Task makeEgg2Async()
{

    while (CookIsBusy)
    {
        //      
        await Task.Delay(100);
    }
}
```

...will the computer return to the main `Test1()` after it get to this line?

```
async Task MakeEggAsync()
{
    await makeEgg2Async();
}
```

...or will it return only after it get to a delay? I know with threading it only returns after you get to a wait.
Sorry I am new to this and I am trying to learn.

Does the computer returns after it gets to an `await` or after it get to a `Task.Delay`? This is what I am really asking.

Comment: You're asking what the code does....couldn't you just set a breakpoint and try it? Or add logging? Why do you need us to do that. We're people, not computers.

Answer (score 1):

[Every `async` method begins executing synchronously](https://blog.stephencleary.com/2012/02/async-and-await.html).

Also, *objects* are awaited, not *methods*. In other words, this code:

```
async Task  MakeEggAsync()
{
  await makeEgg2Async();
}
```

is roughly the same as this code:

```
async Task  MakeEggAsync()
{
  var task = makeEgg2Async();
  await task;
}
```

So the computer returns to `Test1` after the `Task.Delay` is invoked.

Comment: Thanks for the  answered. What would happen if did an await Task.WhenALL with two tasks that did not have any await objects in them ?

Comment: @Echo: `Task.WhenAll` completes when all of its tasks are complete. How the tasks are implemented is immaterial.